# Cakephp 3: Collections getting to middle array entities

Tags: collections, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to build a view that shows the most recent (now four but eventually five) years of data in a chart. I'm able to pull the data successfully in a variable the shows the most recent 4 years(I don't have the fifth year in the database yet). In order to break it down for the view and add some calculations on associated arrays, I have created a collection. I can get to the first and last array entity but can not figure out how to break out the middle two arrays.

```
public function viewAsuFiveYear()
    {
        $asuFiveYearEnrollments = $this->Enrollments->find('all', [
            'contain' => ['Azinstitutions', 'FallFtes', 'FallHeadcounts', 'ProjectedEnrollments', 
                'FallHeadcounts.Locations', 'FallHeadcounts.StudentTypes', 'FallHeadcounts.ResidentStatuses', 'FallHeadcounts.Campuses',
                'FallFtes.Locations', 'FallFtes.StudentTypes', 'FallFtes.ResidentStatuses', 'FallFtes.Campuses']
        ], ['limit' => 5])->where(['azinstitution_id' => 1])->order(['enrollment_year' => 'DESC']);

       $collection = new Collection($asuFiveYearEnrollments);
       $yearone = $collection->first();
       $yearTwo = $collection->take(1, 1);
       $yearFour = $collection->last();

       $collection1HC = new Collection($yearone->fall_headcounts);
       $onCampusesHc1 = $collection1HC->match(['location_id' => 1 ])->match(['campus_id' => NULL]);
       $collection4HC = new Collection($yearFour->fall_headcounts);
       $onCampusesHc4 = $collection4HC->match(['location_id' => 1 ])->match(['campus_id' => NULL]);
       $this->set(compact('asuFiveYearEnrollments', 'azinstitutions', 'yearone', 'yearTwo', 'yearFour', 'onCampusesHc1', 'onCampusesHc4'));
    }
```

I tried ->take (one array, second position) but it times out with that. Not sure what filter I can use to get to the 2nd or 3rd entity array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've figured it out. May not be the best answer but it works. for the second year I skipped the 1st array and grabbed the first array in what was left.
and the same with the third year.

```
$yearTwo = $collection->skip(1)->first();
$yearThree = $collection->skip(2)->first();
```